# Why is the [CLS] token embedding in some Transformer models, such as BERT and ViT, 0-initialized?

Tags: deep-learning, bert-language-model, transformer-model

In the implementations of ViT and BERT I can see they initialize the [CLS] token as a zero-initialized parameter:

`cls = self.param('cls', nn.initializers.zeros, (1, 1, c))`

I know a positional encoding is added to each token embedding, which makes the representation of the [CLS] token not a 0-vector; however, is this intentional? Is the positional encoding what saves the architecture for getting 0-vector representations as output from the Transformer encoder? Because, if we carry out the whole self-attention matrix multiplication softmax(QK^T/sqrt(d))V, where the first row of Q,K,V is a 0-vector (assuming we don't add positional embeddings and have a 0-vector input embedding for the [CLS] token) we get a 0-vector.

I searched papers and blogs; however, I did not find any answers to this.